# Partial circular border using CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to create a partial circular border around an element using pure css. I've been able to achieve the effect to a certain extent in this: http://jsfiddle.net/5MZMj/202/
However, this removes 25% or the border, How do I remove just 5% or say 20% ?
Also, how do I rotate the border (without rotating the content inside)?

Code in jsfiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">4.5</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.two {
    font-size: 24px;
    display:inline;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.one {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    width:30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Edit: image to give an idea of the effect I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKI6N.jpg
Edit2: sorry, I just realized I had linked the wrong jsfiddle, correct one is: http://jsfiddle.net/5MZMj/202/

Comment: The border is part of the `div`. If you want to rotate just the border, then you will have to wrap it in another `div` and rotate that.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove 25%"?

Comment: @Bort: added image to explain better, see:  http://imgur.com/JU78ICT

Comment: I don't think that's possible with CSS. It certainly wouldn't work across most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially solved using psuedo elements, see: http://jsfiddle.net/5MZMj/205/

```
:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #fff;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-42px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Editing margin-top, margin-left and border-right changes the amount of arc to be removed.

[There ought to be a better way though, someway in which editing a single variable changes the amout of arc to be removed]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but a simple hack is to put the upper right circle behind your main div:

```
#f {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5MZMj/199/

Comment: thing is I want the ability to vary percentage from 5% to 25%, that is difficult to do this way

Comment: I think you're talking about partial borders through CSS, which is not possible afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you all, but may be this is the answer.

```
#f
{
    right:-93px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zDNK/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the radius for each corner if that what you mean:

`border-radius: 5px 10px 15px 20px;`

Starting with the top-left corner and going clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take less of a chunk out of the corner, you need to adjust the positioning of the circle.
http://jsfiddle.net/5MZMj/201/

```
#f {
    right: -85px;
    top: -85px;
}
```